# Jquery hover, get the child ul and show

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site which outputs the ul like so:

```
<ul role="primary">
<li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href=" /services/">Services</a>
   <ul class='children'>
      <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href=" /services/accounts-production/">Accounts Production</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-25"><a href=" /services/audit/">Audit</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-27"><a href=" /services/tax-planning/">Tax Planning</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-29"><a href=" /services/business-startup-advice/">Business Startup Advice</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-31"><a href=" /services/accounting-systems/">Accounting Systems</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-33"><a href=" /services/payroll-bureau/">Payroll Bureau</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am using jQuery to add a class to the parent li of parent and I need it so that when that specific li is hovered over the child ul will show.

```
$('ul[role="primary"] li ul.children li').hide();

   $('li:has(> ul)').addClass('parent').mouseover(function() {

   $(this).children().show();

});
```

But its not working, Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `$('li:has(> ul)')`? That is not legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$('ul[role="primary"] li ul.children').hide();
$('ul[role="primary"] li').addClass('parent').hover(
    function(){ //mouseenter 
            $(this).find('ul').show();
    }, function(){//mouseexit
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
    });
```

As you can see, you can use find(), children() or any traversal that suits your code best.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in JavaScript

```
$('ul[role="primary"] li ul.children li').hide();

$('li').has('ul.children').addClass('parent').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('li').show();
});
$('li').has('ul.children').addClass('parent').mouseout(function() {
   $(this).find('li').hide();
});
```

And here the working example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAtzh/2/)

The second part is for hiding again!

Comment: @SteveDevGuy Now it hides it on mouseout, i updated the answer.